# Can I connect a Yamaha Clavinova CLP-230 to a MBAir using USB cable?

Tags: macbook-pro, garageband

I tried, using a USB A to USB B cable but the computer did not recognize the Clavinova CLP-230 in Garageband. Not sure where I am going wrong? Tried a different cable but still no luck. OS 10.13

Comment: First, have you looked at the Yamaha website for manuals and downloads? I would imagine the manual will tell you if it is Mac compatible. Second, what macOS version is on your Mac? Finally, What is the model number of the Clavinova? Please add **ALL** of the answers to your original post (not as a comment)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the Yamaha USB-MIDI driver first:

https://dk.yamaha.com/da/support/updates/usb_midi_driver_for_mac.html

This driver works across all the Yamaha Clavina models with USB port for MIDI.

When you have installed the driver, reboot the Mac and insert the USB-cable from Mac to piano. Then turn on the Piano. Finally start GarageBand, and the new MIDI device should be available for use.